# Styles for specific font in a stack?

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-email, fallback

Let's say I have a font stack such as `font: normal 16px/24px HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold, Arial, san-serif;`

Is there any way in CSS to target the fallback `Arial` font with styles specific to it, for example if I only wanted Arial to be bold?

I feel like using something in the realm of `[style*="Arial"]` would be a starting point, but that would still target ***all*** the fonts in the stack, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you set the base body font to be Arial bold, it will be the fallback on most email clients, except Outlook, where the fallback font is actually Times New Roman.

```
body { 
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table.body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, td { 
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

By doing this, you set the table body, table cells, the Headings, paragraph sizes to Helvetica Neue. If the font is not present, it defaults to the default body style.

This is the full Helvetica Neue Condensed font stack from Rachael Moore. A variation on this CSS could provide you with the look you need.  http://rachaelmoore.name/posts/design/css/web-safe-helvetica-font-stack/

`font-family: "HelveticaNeueBlackCondensed", "HelveticaNeue-Black-Condensed", "Helvetica Neue Black Condensed", "HelveticaNeueBlack", "HelveticaNeue-Black", "Helvetica Neue Black", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", 'TeXGyreHerosCnBold', "Arial Narrow", "Arial", sans-serif; font-weight:800;`

One issue I can see is that the em width of the fonts Helvetica Neue and Arial Bold is really different, so you might see layout issues. That's just my opinion.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a JavaScript for this. There is one CSS property that can help with sizing when a fallback font is used, the *font-size-adjust* property. The *font-size-adjust* property allows you to specify an optimal aspect ratio for when a fallback font is used; if the substitute font has a different aspect ratio than the preferred one, the text’s x-height (roughly the size of its lowercase letters) will be preserved.

Comment: It might work in web but JavaScript don't work in emails.